# How to plot multiple ggplot2 elements and have labels repel/appear?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to create a chart that has multiple lines as well as point elements. The labels for the lines need to be in a legend while the labels for the point need to be on the chart. So far, this is the code I use to create this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
theme_set(theme_minimal())

chart_df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18295, 18302, 18309, 18316, 
18323, 18330, 18337, 18344, 18351, 18358, 18365, 18372, 18379, 
18386, 18393, 18400, 18407), class = "Date"), cum_sum_cases = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 71L, 273L, 517L, 929L, 1333L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), peak = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3745L, NA), peak_label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Actual peak: 3745", 
NA), forecast_cum_sum_cases = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1854, 2363, 3528, 4173), forecast_peak = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3528, 
NA), forecast_peak_label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Forecasted peak: 3528", NA), true_cum_sum_cases = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2019L, 2624L, 
3745L, 4559L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")

#Plot
ggplot(data = chart_df, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=cum_sum_cases, color = "Actual cases"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=true_cum_sum_cases, color = "Ground truth cases"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=forecast_cum_sum_cases, color = "Forecasted cases"), linetype = "twodash", size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual("", values = c("Actual cases" = "darkred", "Ground truth cases" = "green", "Forecasted cases" = "steelblue")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=peak), color = "darkred", size = 2) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y= peak, label=peak_label)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=forecast_peak), colour = "steelblue", size = 2) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y= peak, label=forecast_peak_label)) +
  ylab("Total confirmed cases") +
  xlab("Date")
```

However, I can only see the second point label in this case even when using the `ggrepel` package. Since the two points that are being plotted are close to each other, I need R to automatically separate them if possible. Additionally, is there a way to have the legend actually match the `linetype` argument in the `geom_line()` call?[image]

Comment: Hi, your code is throwing some errors.  Can you simplify a bit and share your dataset via the output of `dput(your.data.frame)`?  Based on the plot code, that would be `dput(chart_data)`, but I think it's probably `dput(chart_df)`.  Additionally, can you please share an image of the plot you are getting?  This will help.

Comment: @chemdork123 updated with `dput` output and picture of chart

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have a look

Comment: Well, right from the start, your second peak is not labeled because the `y=` aesthetic for that one should be `forecast_peak` and not just `peak`... but I'll try to recommend a better way to plot and use `ggplot2` here that can be more useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your immediate issue, the problem of not seeing the label for the second point is due to a typo in your `y=` aesthetic, which should read `y=forecast_peak` and not `y=peak`.  That fixes your immediate issue:

```
p_ptfix <- ggplot(data = chart_df, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=cum_sum_cases, color = "Actual cases"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=true_cum_sum_cases, color = "Ground truth cases"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=forecast_cum_sum_cases, color = "Forecasted cases"), linetype = "twodash", size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual("", values = c("Actual cases" = "darkred", "Ground truth cases" = "green", "Forecasted cases" = "steelblue")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=peak), color = "darkred", size = 2) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y= peak, label=peak_label)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=forecast_peak), colour = "steelblue", size = 2) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y= forecast_peak, label=forecast_peak_label)) +
  ylab("Total confirmed cases") +
  xlab("Date")
p_ptfix
```

[image]

To address the linetype not showing, there are two ways I will show you.  One way is to just make adjustments to the code you are using, whereas another way is to think "Tidy Data" and make your code a bit more scalable and in line with best plotting practices within the tidyverse and all related data analysis packages.

#### Modifying your code to combine Color and Linetype in Legend

To add linetype to your legend, you can use the same method you used for color.  Just know that everything added inside `aes()` other than positioning elements like `x=` and `y=` is used to create a legend by default in `ggplot2`.  `ggplot2` will also try to combine legends where possible.  When changing legend aspects like title and values, it's very important to know that in order to maintain the "connection" between two legends (in this case, `color=` and `linetype=`), your modifications to one legend have to match the other.  So if you change the title of one legend.. you have to make an identical change to the other, etc.

```
p_legendfix <- ggplot(data = chart_df, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=cum_sum_cases, color = "Actual cases", linetype="Actual cases"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=true_cum_sum_cases, color = "Ground truth cases", linetype="Ground truth cases"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=forecast_cum_sum_cases, color = "Forecasted cases", linetype="Forecasted cases"), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("Actual cases" = "darkred", "Ground truth cases" = "green", "Forecasted cases" = "steelblue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(NULL, values=c("Actual cases" = 1, "Ground truth cases" = 1, "Forecasted cases" = 3)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=peak), color = "darkred", size = 2) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y= peak, label=peak_label)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=forecast_peak), colour = "steelblue", size = 2) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y= forecast_peak, label=forecast_peak_label)) +
  ylab("Total confirmed cases") + xlab("Date")
p_legendfix
```

[image]

#### Tidy Data Way

While your setup works, it's a bit overly complicated and quite hard to scale or include additional features.  What if you had 5 lines to plot?  What about wanting to label 10 points?  What if you wanted to change a name of one of the lines?  It's dangerous to have to change the code and much easier if this information could come directly from the data.  I would highly suggest you read about the [principles of Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) to help understand the why and the how.  Regardless, I'll try to give you a "Tidy Data" answer as well to spread the knowledge :).  For this, the idea is going to be to re-arrange your dataset so that we have the following columns:

- **date** - your `x=` aesthetic
- **cases** - your `y=` aesthetic
- **type** - your `color=` and `linetype=` aesthetic that will indicate the type of data ("forcasted", "actual", or "ground truth")
- **peak_df** - a new daset that contains the information on plotting the peak points and the labels of interest

I'm going to be using `gather()` a lot from `dplyr`, which is a lot like the `pivot_longer()` function from `tidyr`.  We'll take it column by column here.  Since I'm going to be gathering and using the column names, I'm going to want to change those first to make it easier for us.  Here we go:

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- chart_df
names(new_df) <- c('date','Actual Cases','peak','peak_label','Forecasted Cases','forecast_peak','forecasted_peak_label','Ground Truth Cases')

new_df <- new_df %>%
  select('date', 'Actual Cases', 'Forecasted Cases', 'Ground Truth Cases') %>%
  gather(key='type', value='cases', -date)
```

That bit of code now fixes it so that we have in `new_df` all the data needed to plot our lines.  For the `peak_df`, it also needs the same columns, and we'll encode the actual label text within the plot call.  I'm manually creating the `peak_df$type` column below because it's just easier with only two values.

```
# pull the one key observation
peak_df <- chart_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(peak!='NA') %>%  #pull the one observation
  select(date, peak, peak_label, forecast_peak, forecast_peak_label) %>%
  gather(key='lab_type', value='cases', -c(peak_label, forecast_peak_label, date))

# it gets me the two lines for peak_df$date and peak_df$cases
# manually entering in peak_df$type now
peak_df$type <- c('Actual Cases', 'Forecasted Cases')
```

For the plot, it is now much easier to combine legends and have control over the plotting.

```
p1 <- ggplot(new_df, aes(x=date, y=cases)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=type, linetype=type), size=1.5) +
  geom_point(data=peak_df, aes(color=type), size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(data=peak_df, aes(label=paste0(type, ":",cases))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name=NULL) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name=NULL, values=c(1,2,1))
p1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@chemdork123 was faster than me! Nonetheless, here's my version of the the tidy way, which also match the linetype in the legend (for which you need the linetype to be defined by a variable).

```
library(tidyverse)

# tidy data frame for the lines
mydf <-
  chart_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("_cases"),
              names_to = "mytype",
              values_to = "myval",
              values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(mytype = case_when(mytype == "cum_sum_cases" ~ "Actual cases",
                            mytype == "forecast_cum_sum_cases" ~ "Forecasted cases",
                            mytype == "true_cum_sum_cases" ~ "Ground truth cases"))


# tidy data frame for the labels
label_df <-
  chart_df  %>%
  select(date = date, label1 = peak_label, val1 = peak, 
         label2 = forecast_peak_label, val2 = forecast_peak)  %>%
  pivot_longer(-date,
                names_to = c(".value", NA),
                names_pattern = "(.)(.)",
                values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  rename(mylabel = l, peak = v)

# and the plot
mydf   %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = myval, color = mytype, linetype = mytype)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = label_df, aes(x = date, y = peak), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = date, y = peak, label = mylabel),
                  data = label_df,
                  inherit.aes = FALSE,
                  force = 1,
                  min.segment.length = 5,
                  point.padding = 1) +
  ylab("Total confirmed cases") +
  xlab("Date")
```